# Python update queue with several asyncio

Tags: python, queue, python-asyncio

I want to update Queue with several asyncio
I receive data from each A,B,C( using websocket and "while true") and then i want to put in the queue and all the provider will be able to write in the same Queue
( I know that maybe i need to use multiThread or something else but i dont find the right way

```
**if __name__ == '__main__':
global_queue = queue.Queue()
asyncio.run(A_Orderbook.data_stream(global_queue))
asyncio.run(B_Orderbook.data_stream(global_queue))
asyncio.run(C_Orderbook.data_stream(global_queue))
print(global_queue.qsize())**
```

Thks

Comment: You probably don’t want to run each coroutine in a separate event loop. You may also want to consider using an asyncio Queue instead.

Comment: Any feedback please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it the following way:

```py
import asyncio


async def worker(worker_name: str, q: asyncio.Queue):
    """Produces tasks for consumer."""
    for i in range(1, 6):
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
        await q.put(f"{worker_name}-{i}")


async def consumer(q: asyncio.Queue):
    """Consumes tasks from workers."""
    while True:
        item = await q.get()
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
        print(item)
        # we need it to ensure that all tasks were done
        q.task_done()   


async def main_wrapper():
    """Main function - entry point of our async app."""
    q = asyncio.Queue()
    # we do not need to await the asyncio task it is run in "parallel"
    asyncio.create_task(consumer(q))  
    await asyncio.gather(*[worker(f"w{i}", q) for i in range(1, 5)])  # create worker-tasks
    await q.join()  # we wait until asyncio.create_task(consumer(q)) consume all tasks
    print("All DONE !")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main_wrapper())
```